# How to implement leptonX theme

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I was trying to add the new leptonX theme provided by ABP framework. But i couldn't find a doc for the MVC project. There is one for the angular. Have anybody tried adding to MVC project?

Comment: Hello, we have an internal issue related to this topic. An article about this will be published at the 5.0 milestone, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web project, you need to run the command:

```
abp add-package Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.LeptonX --prerelease
```

Or

```
dotnet add package Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.LeptonX --prerelease
```

Follow instructions as per Abp Team: https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/themes/lepton-x/commercial/mvc